# fastJSON exception 'Serializer encountered maximum depth of 20'

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, fastjson

I'm using fastjson to serialize an object before I pass it back from my controller to my $.post call in javascript, but I'm getting this error and I don't know why.

The exception is being thrown when I try to call 'fastJSON.JSON.ToJSON(contact)', where 'contact' is a pretty standard object with about 25-30 properties.

```
return Json(new { message = "Contact created", contact = fastJSON.JSON.ToJSON(contact), error = false });
```

and my controller return type is a 'JsonResult'

any thoughts on this?

Comment: Post the class definition.

Comment: Maybe this can works for you: `fastJSON.JSON.Instance.ToJSON(contact)`